# Javascript/Jquery if statement and hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of images that have an opacity of 80%.
When I hover over the image, I use `mouseenter` and `fadeTo('fast' 1);` to make the opacity 100%.
When I hover away from the image, I use `mouseleave` and `fadeTo('fast' 0.8);` to get the opacity back to 80%.

BUT, if the image I hover over has a specific class, I want the opacity to stay 100%, and not change to 80% on mouse leave.

I tried but failed, I hope you guys can help me!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var subject = 'null';

$('.subject').mouseenter(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass(subject) == false) {
        $(this).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }
});
$('.subject').mouseleave(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass(subject) == false {
        $(this).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 0);
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
    }
});


$('.english-link').click(function(){
    $('.english').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.english').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    var subject = 'english';
});
$('.math-link').click(function(){
    $('.math').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.math').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    var subject = 'math';
});
$('.electives-link').click(function(){
    $('.electives').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.electives').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    var subject = 'electives';
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/JDfpc/

Comment: Is the CSS-class called null? You also have a syntax-error on the second line in your mouseleave-callback. You are missing a closing parenthesis in the if-statement.

Comment: how about you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) containing what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not` jQuery selector on your function that fades out your image, like `$('.math:not(.otherclass)').doSomething()`

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

As you plan to fade in function of the `subject` var, you have to make it global.

For the moment, you're redeclaring `subject` each time with `var`, so within the scope of your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, the `subject` hasn't change.

```
var globals = {};            //Your global array

$(document).ready(function(){

   globals.subject = 'null'; //Subject is accessible everywhere in your code now
   
   ...

   

    $('.english-link').click(function(){
        $('.english').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        $('.english').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        globals.subject = 'english';
    });
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/JDfpc/1/) for a working example.

*Note : you can also use HTML 5 `localStorage` to store the subject like `localStorage.subject = 'english'`.*

Comment: Why make it global? Why not make it local to the outer DOM-ready callback? That way it won't pollute the global namespace, but will still be in scope for all functions in the example.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I know the second proposition pollutes the global namespace ; but the first one too?

Comment: At least the first example keeps all your globals in a single global object, but I don't see the point of making it global, unless you really need access to the variables in some other part of your code, which hasn't been stated here. And if you need access to the variable elsewhere, I would still say that global variables are rarely the way to go. It would probably be better to set up some shared scope, or pass the variable to the method if needed. Global variables can easily create a mess.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(#subject).hover(function () {
      (this).fadeTo('fast', 1)
 }, function () {
      if(this).hasClass("subject") {
           (this).css('opacity','1');
      }
      else if {
           (this).fadeTo('fast',.8)
      }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

You have syntax error,try with this

```
$('.subject').mouseenter(function(){
if (($(this).hasClass('subject')) == false) {
    $(this).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $(this).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
  }
});
```

[check here](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Comment: The element will always have the class `subject` since that is what you select on.

Comment: You have introduced the logical error by making `subject` a string literal instead of a variable. You also have unnecessary parenthesis in your example, which makes it kind of hard to read.